# Load files via javascript/jquery without using web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do something like this to make a simple log reader with a navigation on the left side and can display the txt files on the right side one by one:

```
$('.menuItem a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var log = $(this).attr('id');
    $.get(log, function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $('.log').text(data);
    });
});
```

This doesn't work at the moment from what I have discovered since I am trying to use file:// directives instead of http:// with local web services...is there any way to make this work on a local copy?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use AJAX to request `file:///` links.  Doesn't matter if the page is also `file:///`.

Comment: Download something like XAMPP, and run as a local server, so you can have something like `http://localhost/blahblah`

Comment: This is for my business, so I can't use something like xampp :p  If there is no other way to get around this then we will have to try a different approach or setup a very basic web server.  Thanks :)